# How to pass selected row value of table to button click event - Material design - Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

my previous question was not clear. Allow me to ask again clearly as I'm struggling complete my task.

I've mat-table along with checkbox for every row. (No master checkbox). whenever I select the row I should send the values of the selected row to button which is outside of the table.

[if I have a button inside the table, I could do that by accessing the default **ELEMENT** from `*matCellDef="let element"` variable if the button present inside the table.

But I don't know how to pass the selected row value to the button.  I've to do routing based on the value from the selected row.

so far I've.

**HTML**

```
<div><button mat-button  [disabled]="!checkedbtn" (click)='linktomynxtpage()'>link to another page</button></div>

<table #demoTable mat-table [dataSource]="sample" multiTemplateDataRows>
// some ng-container with <th><td>

 <ng-container *ngIf="isAdmin" matColumnDef="actions">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">     
      <mat-checkbox class="select-checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checkedbtn" ></mat-checkbox>        
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row style="text-align:left" *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;" ></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="detail-row"></tr>
</table>
```

**TS**

```
linktomynxtpage(){
    //some logics
    //passing row value. and doing routing
    this.nxtPage.navigate(['/home/particular-user'])

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `(change)` event

```
  <mat-checkbox class="select-checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checkedbtn" (change)="onChange(element)" ></mat-checkbox>  


onChange(row){
  // put the row whenever you want
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. now am able to get the row value. my question is how to pass the selected row value to click event.

Comment: call whatever the function u call in button click in here

Comment: you mean like this 

`callBtn(){
this.onChange(row);
}` . if yes , it gives me **Cannot find name 'row'**

Comment: Yes. I've updated my HTML and ts snippet. could you revisit that

Comment: `onChange(row){
  this.linktomynxtpage(row)
}`

Comment: just changed as you said. issue is. page got navigated suddenly the moment I check the checkbox. but what I want is.  there is a button above the table which is enabled only after the checkbox is checked and that button will take to next pages based row value.

Comment: Thanks for your time. finally, I've solved it by calling service and passing the value for routing